# How to alter varchar length of a table, which is Composite Primary Key?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle

Existing scenario :

1) Field Description

```
userid      varchar(12) Primary Key
```

2) Table contains millions of users(data).

I want change the userid size to varchar(20) without effecting existing data,constraints and struture?

how to achieve this in **`oracle,mssql and mysql`**?

Comment: What damages/effect you foresee when you do a simple alter to column increasing the varchar size ?

Comment: why dont you just alter the table? Increasing size wont cause any damage.
Why don't you also consider using an integer as a primary key instead of a textual value

Comment: If I remember correctly on MS SQL changing data type of column needs DROP of all indexes using it. In case of PRIMARY KEY it can be hard...

Comment: Do you really have to do this in MySQL, SQL Server and Oracle? And like @Yaman says, you should really be using integers as primary keys, as this would reduce indexes and improve performance by a massive degree. As it stands, you just have a poorly designed database. Rather than add to the issue, fix it or suggest the correct fix to your team and you'll all (including users) benefit from the change now and in the future.

Comment: For **Sql Server** `ALTER TABLE Tablename ALTER COLUMN userid VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL`. You need to mention **NOT NULL** in `alter`

Comment: As long as you don't **reduce** the lenght, it should work without any problem.

Comment: What is your requirement...what ever the answers you have got it is correct still you can't find a solution....i hope the question you have asked is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

First never use VARCHAR for Primary key. It slows down Oracle search queries significantly. Use Long or int for the same

You can modify the size of any column in MySql using this statement

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> MODIFY <col_name> VARCHAR(20)
```

It will not alter or change the exsisting data

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, just issue `ALTER table MODIFY` -

`alter table table_name modify (column_name varchar2(20))`

For example,

```
SQL> create table t(text varchar2(12), constraint t_pk primary key (text));

Table created.

SQL> insert into t(text) values ('text');

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> alter table t modify(text varchar2(20));

Table altered.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

`varchar`s don't consume space for the "additional" capacity beyond the data you actually have. You should be able to just alter the table to resize the column without any adverse effects:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY COLUMN userid VARCHAR(20)
```

Answer (score 0):

FOR MYSQL:

```
ALTER TABLE `mdl_user` CHANGE `userid` `userid` VARCHAR( 20 );
```

There can be a data loss if you are reducing the size of column.